# Single SPA Vue images loaded with parent domain not application domain

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-spa

My images in vue single spa app are loaded with root config domain so it returns 404

[image]

My vue.config.js

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");


function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
  filenameHashing: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      libraryTarget: "system",
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('i18n')
      .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
      .type('javascript/auto')
      .use('i18n')
      .loader('@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader')
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
};
```

Dependencies:

```json
 "vue": "^2.5.17",
 "single-spa-vue": "^2.5.1",
 "systemjs-webpack-interop": "^2.3.7",
```

Below is dist folder that serve single spa Vue app

[image]

Does anyone know how to make Vue app load asset image with correct domain? Thank in advance.

Note: My Single SPA Vue app run on port 8111 and root config app run on port 8080

Comment: You should use nginX with 2 different subdomains - e.g. your config app should be deployed to `config.your-domain.com` while the Vue SPA must be deployed to `app.my-domain.com`

Comment: Can I use 1 domain (public api) with different ports for different single spa?

Comment: Most probably yes, but you must be careful when/if referring to your assets by absolute URL to always include the port number.

Comment: Do you mean that url used in image just has public api (without port number)?

Comment: But when I start root config on localhost and reference to single spa application hosted on EC2, the problem still happen (image from single spa application requested from localhost:8080/img/image.png instead http:// ec2_public_ip/img/image.png

Comment: It depends entirely on what you write inside the `src` attribute of the IMG tag - whether it is `@/assets/img/image.png` or `/img/image.png` or `//ec2-address.com/img/image.png` or `require("~@/img/image.png")` or something else.